# Calling JS function from Android Activity

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am calling a simple JS function to set values of some html contents, but its not working 
Here is the JS function

```
function SetEdits(name,email,pic,date)
{
document.getElementById("myPic").src=pic;
document.getElementById("fullname").value=name;
document.getElementById("email").value=email;
}
```

and here is the code from android activity

```
edit.loadUrl("edit.html");
edit.loadUrl("javascript:SetEdits('"+name+"','"+email+"','"+picture+"','"+date+"')");
```

its not settings these fileds.. is there any problem with the synax where i am calling this function in native activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably ending up evaluating the JavaScript before the "edit.html" page has loaded. Try this:

```
// I'm assuming the real path is something like file:///android_asset/edit.html
edit.loadUrl("edit.html");

edit.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getPath() == "edit.html") {
      view.loadUrl("javascript:SetEdits('" + name+"','" + email + "','" +
                   picture + "','" + date + "')");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the javascript for the webview ? 
You have to setup a javascript interface between your app and html.

Here is some details [Webapp guid](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: yup, that was the first thing to do  . . .

Comment: I don't see the javascript interface name when you call the setEdits method

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="13"

Comment: so i have just used 
WebSettings webSettings = edit.getSettings();
 webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Thats ok, I see you want to inject data not to get data via the js interface... My bad.

Comment: no, i am getting these values from database  and just want to show them in that edit.html file

Comment: Another idea. Can you wait a few ms before calling the second loadurl ? Maybe the page is not loaded completely when you call the javascript method

Comment: means i need to check first if the html page is loaded completely or not , if loaded then call this JS function ?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but you can use a handler for now to see if it's working or not in that way. Handler h  = new Handler(); and use the postDelay metod and call the second load in the runnable let's say after 1500ms, it it's work then you can decrease the time.